# phonegap push plugin does not throw registration event on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, push, phonegap-pushplugin

I'm using the [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) for my ionic app to register and receive notifications.
It works perfectly on Android but the registration event is not thrown on iOS.

The problem is i can see that the device is being registered for push notifications:

```
00:00 4/Notify: Push Plugin register called
00:00 4/Notify: Push Plugin register success: <d4fab0e8 85074aa2 f3a33a85 d32a373f f3b5e4f6 bb94aecb 9fe3732d 77eb5c14>
```

But the "registration" event is never called in my app.

```
        // Initialize push notifications for iOs and Android
        var pushObj = PushNotification.init({
          "android": {"senderID": Constants.ANDROIDSENDERID},
          "ios": {"alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true"}, "windows": {}
        });

        console.log('add listener push registration');

        // handle push notifications
        pushObj.on('registration', function (data) {
          console.log('registration successful');
        }
```

The "registration succesful" log message is written on Android but not on iOS.
I've been stuck on this problem for over a day now.
Does anyone know a solution (or a direction for a possible solution) for this problem?

Comment: check the p12 and provisioning certificate configured properly and makes sure you have activate push notification service on you Apple account.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue, it was an error in the source file located at

```
/src/ios/PushPlugin.m
```

Its fixed and a pull request has been raised. The issue can be tracked @ [#646](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/pull/646)

If you can use an unofficial plugin, import this plugin to your project

```
phonegap plugin add https://github.com/pauljacobv/PushPlugin.git
```

it can solve this problem.